Trying to run a JS script that connects to Solana RPC using solana/web3.js
The error shows, bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Solana node version: 1.18.11
I have found some info online but nothing that has helped. This being the most comprehensive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218827/my-javascript-file-wont-run-because-of-bigint-error
Now what I have tried.
Npm run rebuild.
Installing npm python3.
Installing full python.
Updating VS build tools.
Updating Node.JS version.
Deleting node modules and npm install.
npm i node-gyp.
BigInt Buffer.
Double checked dependences.
This is my first time trying to connect to solana RPC.
This is my script.
const { Connection } = require("@solana/web3.js");


const rpcUrl = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(rpcUrl);

// Test connection
(async () => {
  try {
    const version = await connection.getVersion();
    console.log("Solana node version:", version["solana-core"]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to Solana:", error);
  }
})();

If anyone could help It would be greatly appreciated spent all evening in groups and channels asking for help and trying to sort this "simple" step of the development.
best
Dalt.

Could you share the full error

PS C:\Users\dalt9\solana-bot> node solana-bot.js
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Solana node version: 1.18.11
This is all it seems to give me.
I can not click to investigate further.

What version of node are you using?

I updated to 20.12.2 from 18.18.1.
same issue on both of those versions

This typically shouldn't result in an error. The code snippet should still run.

Any suggestions on what to try?
what would you think is the root issue, why is it failing to load bindings and what can I do to test that area?
Also JS is a fallback if C Bindings fail but in this case neither are working, is that correct?
